# How to verify DKIM signature from an e-mail with openssl?

Tags: openssl, dkim

I've set up opendkim for my postfix and now all outgoing mails have DKIM-Signature heading. What I want to do is to verify manually, withoug DNS and external utilities, preferably with openssl only, that messages are getting correct signature.
So as input data I have:

- DKIM-Signature header of an e-mail
- DKIM Selector, DKIM Domain
- DKIM Private Key
- DKIM Public signature if form of a record that I need to put to DNS

The question is how to decrypt and/or verify DKIM-Signature with DKIM Public signature using some CLI utility like openssl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To verify directly from email's source

- Download email, usually an `.eml` file
- Install python
- `pip install dkimpy`
- `dkimverify < email_file.eml`

  Alternatively you can

  - `dkimverify`
  - paste source
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

[source](https://github.com/madacol/knowledge/blob/master/How%20to%20verify%20email%20DKIM%20signatures.md)

### Other methods

- Install **thunderbird**, configure your account, and install the Add-on [Dkim verifier](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/dkim-verifier/)
- If you want to massively verify an **mbox** archive https://github.com/associatedpress/verify-dkim

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it is complicated an utility is best way, but if you insist, here's how to do it.

1. Prepare the headers you need for verification and add the
   dkim-signature at the end without the actual signature hash.
2. Canonicalize the headers according to the canonicalization algorithm used.
3. If a limit is set for the body, you'l need to cut it then canonicalize it to.
4. Compute the body hash and if it is identical to the one in the dkim signature continue.
5. Use OpenSSL to verify the header hash by providing the following parameters:

   a. Header hash.

   b. Canonicalized headers.

   c. Public key

   d. Hashing algorithm used (SHA1 or SHA256).

I cannot provide you with an example command as I have used PHP's openssl_verify() function to do this.

***I would appreciate it if you told me if you already did this and how.***

Comment: Thanks for the steps, I'll try to implement it someday, but as for now we decided it would be more efficient (and faster) to use whole stack - meaning to validate using DNS server and Amavist as part of our mail flow. It slows verification down, a little bit, but assures the DKIM is going to work with real validation services.

Comment: Did you consider OpenDKIM? It's a Linux application you can install and pass an email to it for verification.